# Local or Push notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I have a simple application that shows some videos from a YouTube channel. I need to send a notification to my users when that YouTube channel have a new video.

I've been thinking and I realize that if I use local notifications the app will have to run a method every "5 minutes" and check if there's a new video, BUT when the user closes the app my method will stop running and the app will stop checking for new videos.

Otherwise, I'll use remote notification. I'll store the user device token into a database and check for new videos with PHP. When it happens, I'll send a push to all my users. Unfortunately, this case will overload the server that the PHP is.

My question is: What's the best solution? Is there any way to I keep executing a method when my app is closed?

Comment: Why does the server need to check *every 5 minutes*? I don't know of ANY YouTube channel that posts videos this often.

Comment: I used 5 minutes as an example. Maybe I check every everyday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push is your best option. There isn't a good enough way to keep checking in the background to use local notifications accurately enough. Monitor for new videos on your server as often as you feel necessary and fire a push notification to the user. That model exists in many apps across the app store. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Bill. I'll use push and repeat the PHP file with Cron Job.